# When can I apply for a US B2 visa if my current visa is about to expire?

Tags: visas, usa

I hold an Indian passport and a 10 year B1/B2 visa, expiring in October 2019.
I hope to travel to US in December 2019.
Can I apply for a new B2 visa right now, while my current visa is still valid?
Is there a timeframe defined around this kind of scenario?

Comment: I do not have an official source for this but I believe it is possible to apply now.  They will cancel your current visa "without prejudice" while they are processing your application.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is fine. It's what you would do if you (e.g.) lost the passport with the visa you have.